# Maps in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

My app uses bing map control. I've created new tilelayer with google map(

> http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&z={0}&x={1}&y={2}

) but it doesn't work. I've read something about google doesn't support windows phone. Is it my case too? After that I've tried openstreetmap and it is ok, but no satellite images. Other choice is Nokia map, but I don't know how to use satellite images. This link is from nokia website(

> http://maptile.maps.svc.ovi.com/maptiler/v2/maptile/newest/normal.day/{0}/{1}/{2}/256/png8?token={3}&app_id={4}&lg={5

}) no item to place viewmode.
Any suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use bing maps or google maps? i suggest bing

Comment: I've decided to use bing maps but with custom TileLayer OpenStreetMap. Unfortunately, it doesn't support satellite mode.